# Div inside div not aligning as expected

Tags: css, html, position

You can visit the site I am trying to work on [here](http://thomashall.idesignclass.com).

I am trying to get basically the layout as in the top right box in the bottom right box, but for some reason I cannot get it to float to the right. Is there something I am missing here? It's driving me nuts because my code works in the upper box but not in the lower one.

Here's the HTML.

```
<div id="menu-ad">
        <div>
            <p class="titles">Our Fare</p>
            <p id="ad">Our lunch and dinner menus feature European inspired comfort food accompanied by an extensive bar.</p>
            <a href="#" id="button">VIEW MENU</a>
        </div>
    </div><!--end menu ad-->

    <div id="hours">
        <div>
        </div>
    </div><!--end hours-->
</div><!--end container-->
```

And the CSS.

```
/*menu ad*/

div#menu-ad {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -11px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    width: 268px;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    padding: 11px 11px 10px 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid #b9aea3;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #b9aea3;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div#menu-ad div {
    background: #f9f4df;
    padding: 1.9rem 4rem 2.5rem 2.5rem;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.titles {
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #d6832e;
}

#ad {
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.35;
    color: #4f4d4b;
    margin-top: .5rem;
    width: auto;
}

a#button {
    padding: .6rem 1.3rem .6rem 1.3rem;
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: #fff;
    background: #d6832e;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    bottom: 3.5rem;
}

/*hours*/

div#hours {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -11px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    width: 268px;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    padding: 11px 11px 10px 10p;
    border-left: 2px solid #b9aea3;
}

div#hours div {
    background: #f9f4df;
    padding: 1.9rem 4rem 2.5rem 2.5rem;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks for any help! It's probably something simple and I just need a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to have a typo,

under the style rule for

```
div#hours
```

you have

```
padding: 11px 11px 10px 10p;
```

your missing an 'x' at the end. Which means the padding rule is not being applied

Now this solves the alignment, but the height might not be right now, but I'm sure that should be straight forward

Comment: I knew it was probably something like that. Thanks. And, so this is my updated CSS `div#hours {
 position: relative;
 margin-right: -11px;
 width: 268px;
 height: auto;
 float: right;
 padding: 11px 11px 10px 10px;
 border-left: 2px solid #b9aea3;
}` But it still doesn't follow my width properly.

Comment: You just need to put some content in that inner div.

Comment: you have it set to display: inline-block, set it to display: block if you want it to fully respect the width property - the internal div with the yellow coloring I'm referring to by the way. But putting some content in it should solve it, as long as the content is more that the width of the parent

Comment: also if I may offer some advise, I think you are missing the power of the cascade word of CSS. The two style rules for div#menu-ad & div#hours share almost the same stlying, I would separate all the common rules into a class (i.e. .tile or something), apply the class to both the elements, and then only write the two additional rules for the #hours one. Generally I don't style ids (#'s) as this leads to specific styling, which means can't reuse style rules for other elements, and means lots more typing and large CSS files - anyway my two cents